# Start screen saver the moment I lock the computer on Win XP

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver

Can I change the scheduling of the screen saver, to start as soon as I lock my Win XP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the Windows site:](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/setup/learnmore/tips/liu1.mspx)

**Instantly Activate a Screensaver**

Turn on a screensaver without having to wait by adding a shortcut to your desktop:

1. Click the Start button, and then click Search.
2. In the Search Companion window, click All file types.
3. In the file name box, type *.scr
4. In the Look in box, choose Local Hard Drives (C:) or the drive where you have system files stored on your computer.
5. Click Search.
6. You will see a list of screensavers in the results. Pick a screensaver you want. You can preview it by double-clicking it.
7. Right click on the file, choose Send To, and then click Desktop (create shortcut).
   To activate the screensaver, double-click the icon on your desktop.

If you're part of a domain, you'll see the On resume, password protect check box.

[image]

[To make sure this works everywhere:](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/1189/)

> Open your registry and find the key
>   below.
>
> Create a new DWORD valued called
>   "ScreenSaverIsSecure" and set it to a
>   value from the table below.
>
> (Not in registry) - Users can turn
>   password-protection on and off. 0 -
>   Screen savers are not
>   password-protected. 1 - All screen
>   savers are password-protected. Restart
>   Windows for the change to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

[MoniterES](http://code.google.com/p/monitores/) can do that.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this exactly, but one thing you could do is set the computer to lock when you start the screensaver, and then create a shortcut to the screensaver program (C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr on WinXP) and give it a keyboard mapping like Ctrl-Alt-L.

Edit: I just realized that the screensaver program I gave may not do what I thought it did.  When I last tried something like this, I think I ended up using "[Nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) screensaver" instead of scrnsave.scr.  Nircmd is a pretty sweet free program, with tons of easy commands that allow you to easily automate a bunch of windows tasks.  Anyway, the basic idea is the same, you just create a shortcut to nircmd instead of the screensaver directly.

Comment: That's exactly what I did... Ctrl-Alt-S starts the sreensaver... and it's without Nircmd... only I don't remember how I have done that :-s