# How can I make windows xp display screensaver when computer is locked

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start screen saver the moment I lock the computer on Win XP](https://superuser.com/questions/18764/start-screen-saver-the-moment-i-lock-the-computer-on-win-xp)

can screensaver run when the computer is locked?

Answer (score 2):

not sure you can change windows do to it but you could create a program that locks the computer and runs the screensaver?

To lock the computer:

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"c:\windows\System32\ribbons.scr");

http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2010/09/lock-workstation-without-ctrl-alt-del.html

Answer (score 0):

The XP screensaver has the lock built in.
http://kb.iu.edu/data/acdt.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you set your screensaver properties to display the logon screen on resume (at least I'm pretty sure that XP can do that).