# Autorun screensaver on session lock

Tags: windows-7

The screensaver is currently configured to run after a timeout. So it does.

Is it possible to also make it run automatically immediately after the user has locked the session (as in WinKey+L)?

Comment: This has already been answered over here [http://superuser.com/questions/18764/start-screen-saver-the-moment-i-lock-the-computer-on-win-xp][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/18764/start-screen-saver-the-moment-i-lock-the-computer-on-win-xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution just as good as screen-lock, is to launch the screen-saver, defined as requiring password, using another keyboard shortcut than Win-L.

This is done by creating a desktop shortcut to the screen-saver file (*.scr), then assigning it a keyboard shortcut.

For details see : [How to Immediately Turn on the Screen Saver on an XP Keyboard](http://www.ehow.com/how_7164345_immediately-screen-saver-xp-keyboard.html).